# Python Validate the user entered data problem

Tags: python

I'm new to programing and I'm having trouble with a homework assignment. Every time I run the code and go to put in my data I keep getting stuck when I go to put in my numbers. It brings up my "You entered 2 which is an incorrect value for the project annual increase amount.

Please enter your project annual increase amount in a decimal form such as 2 for 2% or 45 for 45%: "

````
##4.  Ask the user to enter the project annual increase
ProjectAnnIncrease = input('Please enter the your project annual increase in decimal form such as 2 for 2% or 45 for 45%: \n')


##4a. Validate the user entered data that is a decimal and a positive decimal less than .50
while not ProjectAnnIncrease.isdigit() or float(ProjectAnnIncrease) > 0 or float(ProjectAnnIncrease) < 50:
    print('You entered', (ProjectAnnIncrease) , 'which is an incorrect value for the project annual increase amount.\n')
    (ProjectAnnIncrease) = input('Please enter your project annual increase amount in decimal form such as 2 for 2% or 45 for 45%: \n')```
````

Comment: 2 is greater than zero (and it's also less than 50), so the `if` evaluates to true.  If you're expecting this number to be a _percentage_, then you have to divide by 100.  However, any percentage will still be greater than 0, so I'm confused why you're even checking that condition...

Comment: Thank you so much, John Gordon. I realize now I was mixing up my < and > symbols. ‍♀️

Comment: Also just a formatting suggestion: your lines are too long. Try breaking them into shorter lines, it'll help both your and other readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your comparison signs the opposite, you want to continue asking if you're lower than 0 or higher than 50

```
while not ProjectAnnIncrease.isdigit() or float(ProjectAnnIncrease) < 0 or float(ProjectAnnIncrease) > 50:
```